# Howto :: dynamically add string to command

Tags: bash, if-statement, dynamic

unfortunately I'm struggling with some kind of a "simple idea". 
Within my Bash Script I'm checking a variable and if it's set I'll print output to the user (kind of verbose / show output).

```sh
[ ! -z $boolVerbose ] && fnc_print2user "i" "Print to user in one-line"
```

That's working pretty fine for me. 
Now I have commands which don't allow suppressing their output, so I want to hide it or show it if my variable above is set/not empty.

I tried the following (and several other options..), to run the command as it is (means: showing output), expect the variable is not set/is empty, then it should append "&> /dev/null" to the command before (so suppress the output).

```sh
commandWithOutput $([ -z $boolVerbose ] && echo " &> /dev/null")
```

The script is running fine if I set my verbose Variable, but if it's not set my commandWithOutput throws an error that there're invalid arguments set (if I hard code to suppress every time it's working like charm).

Is it possible to do some kind of dynamic command adjustments like above in a one-liner or do I have to built real if-else statements with different commandWithOutput methods inside?
Thanks in advance for your ideas & help! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this roughly gives you what you wanted :

```
commandWithOutput &> /dev/$([ -z "$boolVerbose" ] && echo null || echo stdout)
```

Answer (score 1):

Redirect the output to a different file descriptor. Use `exec` to redirect this descriptor to output or to /dev/null as you need.

```
#!/bin/bash
for hide in 0 1 ; do
    if ((hide)) ; then
        exec 3>/dev/null
    else
        exec 3>&1
    fi
    echo $hide: something >&3
    exec 3>&-
done
```